# Zend Framework and MCImageManager

Tags: zend-framework, tinymce, mcimagemanager

Anybody ever integrated MCImageManager and Zend Framework? I want to use MCImageManager in standalone mode (not as part of TinyMCE). I'm really at a loss here - don't know where to put any of the files. Do I need to create a view helper that somehow references the main index.php file of MCImageManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I just added the whole imagemanager directory to my public directory. That way I can just treat it like any other static files (images, css, js, etc).

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? Has anybody ever set this up as a view helper?